# React-native on Android - cannot compile app

Tags: detox

I followed all the instructions to setup Android but when I try to compile it complains it cannot find the modules required in `DetoxTest.java`

```
/Work/mine/detoxJestRn/android/app/src/main/java/com/detoxjestrn/DetoxTest.java:3: error: package android.support.test.filters does not exist
import android.support.test.filters.LargeTest;
                                   ^
/Work/mine/detoxJestRn/android/app/src/main/java/com/detoxjestrn/DetoxTest.java:4: error: package android.support.test.rule does not exist
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
                                ^`
```

Comment: Same issue i'm having with detox 9.0.4, RN 0.56 and gradle:3.1.0. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `DetoxTest.java` file in the correct folder (`androidTest`).

For example:

```
$ find android/app/src -name '*.java'
android/app/src/androidTest/java/com/[your.package]/DetoxTest.java
android/app/src/main/java/com/onova/[your.package]/MainActivity.java
android/app/src/main/java/com/onova/[your.package]/MainApplication.java
```